# How can I read in (cin) 2 consecutive words in a line of input, that has more than 2 words?

Tags: arrays, split, cin, c-strings

I need to read in values from the user, such as license plate, name, phone number, and service type.

I already got how to read it in if the user uses the return character after each input, ie:

```
   A36 HTY
   John Doe
   (263)7742336
   Bronze
```

But how can I read these values into my array if they're all on one line? I can read in word by word, but I need to be able to read in both halves of the license plate, and both the first and last name into one spot in the array.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: It is always a good idea to show some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

read the entire line and then use your software's programming to check whether there is any white space(s) in between the non-white spaces, and if there is, break the read string at the white space(s) into two different strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isspace.

Use this link for assistance: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isspace-in-c-and-its-application-to-count-whitespace-characters/

In this example, they use isspace for counting the number of whitespaces in a string. You can change the code to save each word in different string. Since I didn't write cpp for quite time now, I don't want to give you example that might be incorrect.

```
// input sentence 
char buf[50] = "Geeks for Geeks"; 
ch = buf[0]; 

// counting spaces 
while (ch != '\0') { 
    ch = buf[i]; 
    if (isspace(ch)) 
        count++; 

    i++; 
} 

// returning number of spaces 
return (count);
```